# \n doesnt make new line when display in html/page using sails

Tags: html, string, underscore.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

hi would like to know whether sails has its own function to format string variable to html? I have this scenario...

in my controller, I have a variable whose value is something like this:

```
var str = "Pellentesque habitant \r\nmorbi tristique senectus et\nnetus et malesuada fames ac turpis \negestas.";
```

when I display it as html page it will display plain as this. (1 paragraph only)

```
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
```

but in view source

```
Pellentesque habitant 
morbi tristique senectus et
netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
egestas.
```

I'm searching for the possible solutions for this, and found about Underscore string (https://www.npmjs.org/package/underscore.string) I havent tried it yet, I'm just thinking that there's other possible solutions out there without installing another module...

Or is there any sails equivalent of php function nl2br?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `white-space: pre-wrap` or the equivalent to get the newlines. By default, line feeds in HTML text are just more white space.